# Cloud Firestore CollectionReference query field

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Flutter and Firebase Cloud Firestore. Please, how can I query a CollectionReference by a field? Like:

```
* database
** collection
*** document
**** field (string) to query
```

Comment: I suggest starting with the documentation. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore

Answer (score 2):

You have to query your collection using `where` method. Then, you get all documents that match the criteria.

```
firestore.collection('myCollection').where('yourField', isEqualTo: 'any');
```

Comment: Hi, friend! Thank's for your answer! Complementing my question, I'd like to query a ```string``` *started* with the text that I'd like to search.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this and it works

```
CollectionReference getRecord() {
    try {
      CollectionReference collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("collection-one").document("document one").collection("collection-two").where('field name', isEqualTo: 'string value');
      return collectionReference;
    } catch (e) {
      print('throw:' + e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```